# React component with two sets of children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children

I'm creating a component that needs to take in two sets of children and to be placed in two different parts of a component.

```
let CreditCardForm = ({icons, fields}) => (
  <div>
    <div className='some'>
      <div className='special'>
        <div className='nesting'>
          {icons}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {fields}
  </div>
)

let CreditCardFormUsage = () => {
  let icons = () => (
    <Icons>
      <IconBogus/>
      <IconVisa/>
      <IconPaypal/>
      <IconMore/>
    </Icons>
  )

  let fields = () => (
    <CreditCardFields>
      <FieldCardNumber/>
      <FieldName/>
      <FieldExpirey/>
      <FieldCCV/>
    </CreditCardFields>
  )
  return (
    <CreditCardForm icons={icons} fields={fields}/>
  )
}
```

The code above should work, my question is it possible to grab those property values based on the children in the element itself, and have something more natural?

```
<CreditCardForm>
  <Icons>
    <IconBogus/>
    <IconVisa/>
    <IconPaypal/>
    <IconMore/>
  </Icons>
  <CreditCardFields>
    <FieldCardNumber/>
    <FieldName/>
    <FieldExpirey/>
    <FieldCCV/>
  </CreditCardFields>
</CreditCardForm>
```

Comment: Were you able to achieve what you wanted from either of our answers or are you looking for a different solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, `this.props.children` will return an array so if you always want to load specific children, then just reference those children by index in your wrapper. Then you could just turn `icons` and `fields` into wrapper components. Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/30083/). See how the `render` method of `App` is exactly what you want.

CreditCardForm render:

```
<div>
    <div className='some'>
      <div className='special'>
        <div className='nesting'>
          {this.props.children[0]}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {this.props.children[1]}
 </div>
```

Fields and Icons render:

```
<div>{this.props.children}</div>
```

App render:

```
<CreditCardForm>
    <Icons>
        <IconBogus />
    </Icons>
    <Fields>
      <FieldCardNumber />
      <FieldName />
    </Fields>
</CreditCardForm>
```

Comment: At this solution the order is important, isn't it? Is there an option where it identifies the element and place is based on that?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do it with child props. Read more @docs:

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html

And of course check out **React.Children**

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children

Comment: I've messed around with digging in through the children props before and searching for a specific child via component name. Is this the only way to do it? And at what performance cost?

Comment: only one mentioned in docs, as far as i know, so yes. I would not mind about performance, in most cases it's fast enough to not be noticed, if you will have problems, try caching stuff and not rerendering full view on every state change. this might help: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html

Comment: If talking about speed, check immutable data, it makes comparison a lot faster for complex data sets. works great together with pure render mixin https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/ and it's more clear what is what while using immutable. I think code clarity is big thing.