# Index children of React component with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a component that has multiple sets of children.

The question [React component with two sets of children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181333/react-component-with-two-sets-of-children) suggests to index `children`, as in `props.children[0]`. This works great in JavaScript.

But in TypeScript, I'm getting a type error, even though the code works fine at runtime.

```js
function MyComponent(props: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return <>
    ...
    {props.children[0]}
    ...
    {props.children[1]}
    ...
  </>;
}
```

TypeScript fails with the following error messages on `props.children[0]`:

```
Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.
ts(2533)
```

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'string | number | boolean | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.
ts(7053)
```

How do I make it typecheck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Typescript that your component needs multiple children by putting the array brackets:

```js
function MyComponent(props: { children: React.ReactNode[] }) {
// ...
}
```

If your component accepts exactly 2 children, a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) would be preferable so that Typescript will enforce having 2 children:

```js
function MyComponent(props: { children: [React.ReactNode, React.ReactNode] }) {
// ...
}
```

If your component accepts 2 or more children, you can specify a tuple with a rest element:

```js
function MyComponent(props: { children: [React.ReactNode, ...React.ReactNode[]] }) {
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ReactNode[]` instead of `ReactNode`

```
function MyComponent(props: { children: React.ReactNode[] }) {
  return <>
    {props.children[0]}
    {props.children[1]}
  </>;
}

function TestComponent() {
  return <MyComponent>
    <span>Element 1</span>
    <span>Element 2</span>
    {'string test'}
    {2}
    {true}
  </MyComponent>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWQJ4GE4FsAOCCmYUAFDgE5w4DOAXIgN6IQAWMANgCZmF0BK%20AQ2gA6fkKgA5OB3wBtALqIAvgEoGAWABQiRNyggySADwA%20LTp31ylKsJbsuhWQAZ5S8xasVqd1p25gsgCMbh5GAPQmANxa7ppaoJCwCIgAKvhUUJi4BETEavQeegbGaNl4YIRQZtoWRlQ4AmAmAKJs%20FhViEERDU01Foj1jc1tHV0ATL0jA54A5JlkMGAA5ohQGVBzcYP0EzueUGQg%20AcRZdgVVTVKQA)

Answer (score 1):

If your component always attempts to render **at least 2** child nodes, then you should explicitly type the `children` parameter that way:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbxgTzAUzgJTQQwMYwCiANmiGgHYwA0cK6WuBAchACZoC+cAZlBCDgByKExhCA3ACgpPAK4UCwCBTgBZZAGEBkCpRgAKMPzABnAFyIpcOHgAWwYm1EVLAbWz4YrDrU8t2NFoAOlDRHDYVYmRGLx80NwBdROlOAEpLfyJSciorG1EYOShVAB4APmsbOFDgqpsEYwgzYPtHZ0o3AAZEznqa0P7Gk1NWhycXNwBGXv7aqtKAenLUmXlFGGVVAEEwMDgDDNiCEjJ9fLhC4tUDftKNbXAVfXKERYAqfrgAP1+--++VQAKqgMEIELZxh1XHAkhI4JwhHBgKY4BQIPAcKZTMAAOYUHAAI1IdAgdFBwghbQmlHcWXifjEDIGwXpgSSKQRQjq1TgIPQqIgPDgTXQsBiQmp0KROFEyMUOhwm2JaB5vL5FKESSRKLRGLgWJx+KJJJgZPoYI8TMCjLiNpZbI4HO5X2qAGUIMU8Bg7Fi4F04GgcvoDKY0nBCXJ4DBZbi0PBRABHOTAUSogBMwQM6YAzOn0+H3os+rylg8dM8qJUbGlVkA)

```ts
import {type ReactElement, type ReactNode} from 'react';

function MyComponent(props: {
  children: [ReactNode, ReactNode, ...readonly ReactNode[]];
}): ReactElement {
  return <>
    ...
    {props.children[0]}
    ...
    {props.children[1]}
    ...
  </>;
}
```

By doing so, TypeScript will emit a compiler error diagnostic if you don't provide at least two children:

```ts
function App (): ReactElement {
  return (
    <MyComponent>{/*
     ~~~~~~~~~~~
  Type '{ children: []; }' is not assignable to type '{ children: [ReactNode, ReactNode, ...ReactNode[]]; }'.
    Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
      Type '[]' is not assignable to type '[ReactNode, ReactNode, ...ReactNode[]]'.
        Source has 0 element(s) but target requires 2.(2322) */}
    </MyComponent>
  );
}
```

Similarly, when you only provide one child node:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbxgTzAUzgJTQQwMYwCiANmiGgHYwA0cK6WuBAchACZoC+cAZlBCDgByKExhCA3ACgpPAK4UCwCBTgBZZAGEBkCpRgAKMPzABnAFyIpcOHgAWwYm1EVLAbWz4YrDrU8t2NFoAOlDRHDYVYmRGLx80NwBdROlOAEpLfyJSciorG1EYOShVAB4APmsbOFDgqpsEYwgzYPtHZ0o3AAZEznqa0P7Gk1NWhycXNwBGXv7aqtKAenLUmXlFGGVVAEEwMDgDDNiCEjJ9fLhC4tUDftKNbXAVfXKERYAqfrgAP1+--++-QAKg5THAAFIAZQAGnQcABzIRgoRtCaUIRwJr7NAAD3QBDB9AwQg8YnifjJgRCoSy8SSiSE-QA7g57Jc0ABHOTAURgkByYibMCkWzjDoUWgAIzk8CiMRwcFMwAo8JFqLYcCZODBTQAbsAOGxggYAEwAdgALABWNJwd6LPrVaqlNjAXXlJau913RYPHTPKiVGxpVZAA)

```ts
function App (): ReactElement {
  return (
    <MyComponent>{/*
     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects type '[ReactNode, ReactNode, ...ReactNode[]]'
    which requires multiple children, but only a single child was provided.(2745) */}
      <div></div>
    </MyComponent>
  );
}
```

But as soon as you provide at least two, the diagnostic disappears:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbxgTzAUzgJTQQwMYwCiANmiGgHYwA0cK6WuBAchACZoC+cAZlBCDgByKExhCA3ACgpPAK4UCwCBTgBZZAGEBkCpRgAKMPzABnAFyIpcOHgAWwYm1EVLAbWz4YrDrU8t2NFoAOlDRHDYVYmRGLx80NwBdROlOAEpLfyJSciorG1EYOShVAB4APmsbOFDgqpsEYwgzYPtHZ0o3AAZEznqa0P7Gk1NWhycXNwBGXv7aqtKAenLUmXlFGGVVAEEwMDgDDNiCEjJ9fLhC4tUDftKNbXAVfUrq6tK2YAA3cqXPn-6Ng+31+i3+r3eiweOmeVAhaVWQA)

```ts
function App (): ReactElement {
  return (
    <MyComponent>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </MyComponent>
  );
}
```